# How can I express a family of polynomials fulfilling these constraints?

Tags: polynomials, optimization, soft-question, computer-science, computational-mathematics

Can I express somehow the family of polynomials $ p\in P \subset \mathbb P$ fulfilling

$$p(t) = \sum_{k=0}^N c_k t^k$$

1. $p'(0)=1$
2. $p(0)=0$
3. Monotone and smooth function $t\to f(t) \text{  for  }\ t\in [0,255]$.
4. $p(255) = v_{max}$

?

---

**Own work:** I am aware that we can create linear equation systems and conditions 1 and 2 boil down to : $$\cases{c_0 = 0\\c_1=1}$$
Condition $4$ will give us a linear equation added to the two above.
But then condition $3$ are not so easy to express in the same way. Any ideas?

---

**For context:** The application is for design of non linear remapping functions for [run length coders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). In other words we want to represent run lengths using $8$ bits but we have potentially a lot longer run lengths present.

In practice values anywhere in $[0,v_{max}]$

Answer (score 1):

Smoothness is automatic for any polynomial, but as far as I know, there is no simple way to write down the monotonicity constraint as a constraint on the coefficients.

In practice, you might be able to work with a convenient subspace of all monotonic polynomials? For example, polynomials of the form

$$p(t) = \int_0^t q(s)^2 \,ds$$
$$q(t) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{N-1}} c_k t^k.$$

Comment: Ah yes, this is a nice trick. Just being the square of another polynomial won't work for the first two constraints first derivatives would be discontinous for 0, which can't happen for polynomials. But integral of square..